# Can I turn a Pandas Dataframe with dates and values into 3d numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas df where the first column is the date and time and the rest of the columns represent depths (ascending), the values in the columns are current magnitude. In order to use pcolormesh I would like to change the df into a numpy array where the dimensions are [Time, Depth, Mag].

This is where I am now:

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('test.txt')

[image: my data frame structure]

Comment: Isn't your problem overdetermined? Once you select a date/time and a depth you only have a single magnitude value, so I think you would still end up with a 2D array

Comment: for pcolormesh I need X,Y,Z . My problem is plotting this. I would welcome any solution to the problem.